# How to return multiple rows from result set in java?

Tags: java, database, selenium-webdriver

I have a query, which returns multiple rows to result set. now i need to return total rows in to the application which calling this function.

I tried with this code:

```
  final PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query);

        rs = ps.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {
            result = rs.getInt(1);
        }
```

by this code i am able to return only one value.
 Now i want to return multiple rows

Answer (score 3):

Create [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) of `Integer` and add `result`, return that array list.

```
ArrayList<Integer> resultList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
while (rs.next()) {
        result = rs.getInt(1); 
        resultList.add(result);
    }
return resultList;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use below code :

```
public static List<String> getSqlQueryResult(String sqlQuery) {
        List<String> lst = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            Statement stmt = conSql.createStatement();
            ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery(sqlQuery);
            ResultSetMetaData rsmd = res.getMetaData();
            while (res.next()) {
                for (int i = 1; i <= rsmd.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                    lst.add(res.getString(i));
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return lst;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This code Hope this helps you

final PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query);

```
      ResultSet rs=ps.getResutlSet();
      ResultSetMetaData rsmd=rs.getMetaData();
      for(int i=1;i<=rsmd.getRowCount();i++){

      String resut=rsmd.getString(i);
    }
```

Comment: Hi, Ajay but there is no getRowCount() method exist for ResultSetMetaData, its rsmd.getColumnCount()

Answer (score 0):

In this line  `result = rs.getInt(1);` result is getting replaced each time with a new value.
A good alternate would be to store the values in a list then return the list provided the method return type should be List

Comment: @SubbaraoGaddam you are welcome,If you have any other query then feel free to ask

Answer (score 0):

Result set will contain the number of rows returned by the query.
Using result set object.next we can easily go through this rows of data.
In the above code you have only getting one value.
if result set contain more than one value.
then get this values using the index.

```
while(rs. next)
{

result1=rs.getInt(1);//this will get the two value in each row.
result2=rs.getInt(2);


}
```

if there are are more than one value then use that much index `rs.getint(1)`....`rs.getInt(10)`
also for Strings `rs.getString(2)`